# BABE halts at block 100

Tags: consensus, babe

```
2023-12-26 11:46:18.019  WARN tokio-runtime-worker babe: Error with block built on 0x54a0fbd3703e9d3311c3f51913714b84fc7b09b143251fcaf826dcdc6cf1e388: Import failed: Expected epoch change to happen at 0x1b4ff7fe1d7a8dc529e1e023670002f4c5cff9df8bcfd1d7e78eb045e37031ff, s283936063
```

How to resolve this? Haven't found much insights on google yet.

- Our node: https://github.com/webb-tools/tangle

Comment: please elaborate a bit more on your setup in this project. I would guess this is related to an Epoch change failing

Comment: It was due to a misconfigured runtime, failing to update the session config to use Babe over periodic sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to:

- Check that you've configured your session pallet to use Babe and not periodic sessions (this was the issue).
- Not update the EPOCH length mid runtime (another issue common from the past).